Retrieve optimal hyperparameters from Optuna in Python
I'm running Optuna on a large collection of hyperparameters for optimizing a neural net. After completing a study, is it possible to get an estimate of what the optimal hyperparameter settings would be?
For complex hyperparameter spaces the best trial does not always seem to have all the hyperparameters at the optimal values. I know I can inspect the results visually in the optuna dashboard, specifically the hyperparameter relationships section. From this I can roughly estimate what settings work well, but it feels very inexact. Does Optuna try to estimate what settings work best and can they be retrieved?
